# Who's the kid at the funeral

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the funeral, the camera slowly shows the remaining heroes.
However there's a kid at back, standing completely alone, who is he?

(If my memory serves me right, he's shown after Hawkeye's family.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's Harley Keener, from Iron Man 3. He's the little kid who helps Tony charge his suit when he crashes.
He looks different because the actor is a lot older now.